# How to ignore big cookies in varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to ignore requests with big cookie size. We have some requests dropped in varnish due to "BogoHeader     Header too long: Cookie: xyz". How can it be done in VCL? I didn't find any len, length or strlen function in VCL, I know that it can be done in the vcl_rcev phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strlen()` feature won't help to fix your problem. Varnish discards the request due to the large `Cookie` header **before** `vcl_recv` is executed. If you don't want those requests to be discarded you need to check and adjust some runtime parameters: `http_req_hdr_len`, `http_req_size`, `http_resp_hdr_len`, etc.

In any case, if you are still interested in the `strlen()` feature, it would be trivial to add it to the `std` VMOD, but that support doesn't exist at the moment. You could consider using an existing VMOD including utilities like `strlen()` (or implement it on your own), but that's probably too much work. Finally, you could consider using a hacky approach using just VCL and a regexp:

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^.{1024,}$") {
    ...
}
```